# How to enable both ethernet interfaces at Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, ethernet

I have a machine with two ethernet cards and internet connection, on which Ubuntu 12.04 is installed.
Both ethernet cards can take ip adress automatically say,

```
eth0:47.168.137.14 and eth1:47.168.137.15
```

I can ping eth0 but can not ping eth1.

Is there a special setting for gettting both ethernet interface active and reachable at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Are both the interfaces activated? Try running ifconfig on the terminal and see what states the two interfaces are in.

If the other interface is down it might help to do

```
ifconfig eth1 up
```

Comment: Why eth1 does not get up automatically while getting ip address.

Comment: If you go the the file /etc/network/interfaces there you can add a line saying auto eth1 and then it will automatically start on boot

Comment: After rebooting the machine, I have run the "ifconfig eth1 up" command statement. It does not solve mu queation. What makes it not to work at second attempt.